# Convert wordpress custom field into single array

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am converting wordpress custom fields into one single array in the wp database. I am able to do it but I have duplicated entries. I just need one. Please guide me. Thanks!

**Before running my code:**
[image]

**After running my code:**
[image]

****What I actually want:****
[image]

My code:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( 'migrate' !== filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'action' ) ) {
        return;
    }
 
    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'any',
    ] );
    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        return;
    }
 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        
        $field_id_1 = 'gallery';
        $field_value_1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1, false );
        
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1, $field_value_1);
    }
} );
```

Comment: In the loop allow first iteration to update, and all other to delete_post_meta()

Comment: @Mulli Thanks for commenting. Do you have any example for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( 'migrate' !== filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'action' ) ) {
        return;
    }
 
    $query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'any',
    ] );
    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        return;
    }
 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        
        $field_id_1 = 'gallery';
        $field_value_1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1, false );
        
        delete_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1 );

        add_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1, $field_value_1);

    }
} );
```

@Mulli I got it working this way. Instead of updating the post_meta, I decide to delete the post_meta first and then add_post_meta. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

See the relevant part:

```
    $first=true;
    $field_id_1 = 'gallery';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        
        $field_value_1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1, false );

        if ($first){
            update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1, $field_value_1);
            $first = false;
        else delete_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $field_id_1, $field_value_1);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error with if else.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I meant the duplicates are still there. https://pastecode.io/s/xedpwmuv